# How to read the thread buffer only when a new sample is available?

Tags: python, serial-port, sampling

The following code should read the serial interface into log file. The code can log with significantly high sampling rates (yes, serial synchronization is missing). But since the code is faster than the data rate of the serial device (which should be the case), it reads duplicate points.

Clarification edit: As we can see from the source code, thread is reading the serial port and writing it to the buffer `rawData`. Another function `getSerialData()` should unpack the `rawData` into 4 variables and write to the log file. But as it is faster than data rate of serial device, it reads `rawData` even when no new reading available. I would like to make the function `getSerialData()` unpack `rawData` only when thread writes new data to `rawData`.

<del>I want to make sure that the code only gets last sample from serial device. This could be done by comparing the new sample with the previous sample, but it is too slow.</del>

<del>There are many examples of how it is done, but not for a raw connection.</del>

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from threading import Thread
import serial
import time
import collections
import struct
import copy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import h5py


class serialPlot:
    def __init__(self, serialPort, serialBaud, bufferLength, dataNumBytes, numVal):
        self.port = serialPort
        self.baud = serialBaud
        #self.plotMaxLength = bufferLength
        self.dataNumBytes = dataNumBytes  # number of bytes for single value
        self.numVal = numVal
        self.rawData = bytearray(numVal * dataNumBytes)
        self.data = []
        for i in range(numVal):   # give an array for each type of data and store them in a list
            self.data.append(collections.deque(
                [0] * bufferLength, maxlen=bufferLength))
        self.isRun = True
        self.isReceiving = False
        self.thread = None
        self.plotTimer = 0
        self.previousTimer = 0

        print('Trying to connect to: ' + str(serialPort) +
              ' at ' + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')
        try:
            self.serialConnection = serial.Serial(
                serialPort, serialBaud, timeout=4)
            print('Connected to ' + str(serialPort) +
                  ' at ' + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')
        except:
            print("Failed to connect with " + str(serialPort) +
                  ' at ' + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')

    def readSerialStart(self):
        # start thread if not started yet
        if self.thread == None:
            self.thread = Thread(target=self.retrieveData)
            self.thread.start()
            # Block till we start receiving values
            while self.isReceiving != True:
                time.sleep(0.01)

    def getSerialData(self, bufferLength):
        hdf5Buffer = [[0 for x in range(self.numVal)] for y in range(
            bufferLength)]  # Create array to hold data
        # Calculate time delta between data points
        currentTimer = time.perf_counter_ns()
        # the first reading will be erroneous
        self.plotTimer = int((currentTimer - self.previousTimer) / 1000)
        self.previousTimer = currentTimer

        for e in range(bufferLength):
            privateCopy = copy.deepcopy(self.rawData[:])
            for i in range(self.numVal):
                bytedata = privateCopy[(i * self.dataNumBytes):
                                       (self.dataNumBytes + i * self.dataNumBytes)]
                value, = struct.unpack('f', bytedata)
                # get the latest data point and append it to our array
                self.data[i] = value
            for f in range(self.numVal):
                hdf5Buffer[e][f] = self.data[f]
            hdf5Buffer[e].insert(0, self.plotTimer)
        return hdf5Buffer

    def retrieveData(self):    # retrieve data
        time.sleep(0.1)  # give some buffer time for retrieving data
        self.serialConnection.reset_input_buffer()  # flush input buffer
        while (self.isRun):
            # read n bytes into array (rawData) and return num of bytes read
            self.serialConnection.readinto(self.rawData)
            self.isReceiving = True

    def close(self):
        self.isRun = False
        self.thread.join()
        self.serialConnection.close()
        print('Disconnected...')


def main():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    portName = 'COM15'
    baudRate = 230400
    bufferLength = 10     # number of samples buffered before saving it to HDF5
    dataNumBytes = 4      # number of bytes for single data point
    numData = 4     # number of data points in single sample
    rawData = bytearray(numData * dataNumBytes)

    s = serialPlot(portName, baudRate, bufferLength,
                   dataNumBytes, numData)   # initializes all required variables
    # Starts background thread
    s.readSerialStart()

    dataArray = s.getSerialData(bufferLength)
    while(True):
        # Prepare data to write
        dataArray = s.getSerialData(bufferLength)
        '''
        PROCEDURE FOR WRITING LATEST DATA INTO HDF5
        '''
        # TESTING
        print(str(dataArray[-1]), end='                                 \r')

    s.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
        try:
            sys.exit(0)
        except SystemExit:
            os._exit(0)
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how serial ports work. A serial port can only read the data that is sent to it, and that data is provided to the application program only once (assuming you have an OS that works correctly). There is no *"sampling"* of the serial port (in the manner you think) . If you're "reading" duplicate data, then suspect a program bug or the source that is generating/sending that data.  If the duplicate data is actually valid, then your program has to deal with that.  BTW you overuse the word *"it"*, and you are unclear as to what you are referring.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language. Polling (or sampling) is not the right term here. I revised my question.